# reconocer por medio de Geolocalización la llegada de una persona a determinado sitio

Tags: javascript, android, json, ionic

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Ionic y quiero hacer que un determinado sitio reconozca la llegada de una persona (dispositivo). y mande un aviso diciendo que se llego a tal sitio determinado.

Comment: Bienvenido Freddy a SOes. Creo que debes editar tu pregunta y escribir lo que tienes hecho ya. Consulta [como preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [como crear un ejemplo minimo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sin suficientes datos no podemos reproducir tu problema y ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

No es muy complicado, este seria el pseudo algoritmo:

1. Tomar una posición cada X tiempo. Descartar posiciones con precision menor a un epsilon dado como constante.
2. Para cada posición, calcular la distancia a el o los puntos de control (el centro de cada geo-cerca) usando por ejemplo la [formula de Vincenty](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmulas_de_Vincenty) o el teorema de pitágoras que para distancias cortas lo suficientemente preciso.
3. Si la distancia es menor que el radio de la geo-cerca, esta dentro, sino esta afuera.

En la practica esta es una posible implementación:

- Instalar e importar el componente: [$cordovaGeolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)
- Descargar e importar una librería que resuelva el calculo de la distancia (o hacer tu propia implementación) como por ejemplo, alguna de [geodesy](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy).

Aquí un ejemplo aproximado de como se usa:

```
var geocerca = { 
   latitude: 12.123,
   longitude: -3.12332,
   radio: 120000, // 120 metros, esta en mm
};

module.controller('nombre', ['$scope','$cordovaGeolocation','$interval',
  function ($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $interval) {
    $interval(function(){
        var opt = {
            timeout: 180000,          // 3 minutos maximo
            enableHighAccuracy: false // si false, permite gps asistido por wifi.
        };
        var geo = $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opt);
        geo.then(function (pos) {
                var pos = new LatLon(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                var geoFence = new LatLon(geocerca.latitude, geocerca.longitude);
                // compruebas la distancia entre los puntos 
                if (pos.distanceTo(geoFence) < geocerca.radio) {
                   // si entra aquí, esta dentro de la geocerca...
                   $scope.ejemplo = "Estas dentro de la geocerca!";
                }
            },
            function error(err) {
                // hubo un error, comunicar o hacer lo que sea apropiado.

            }
        );
     }, 5000); // cada 5 segundos.
  }
]);
```

Sin mas información es difícil dar una respuesta mas precisa.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo donde hay un método Javascript donde obtiene la ciudad. Espero te sirva. http://marcodetrabajo.com/widget-meteorologia-jquery/

```
var WeatherApi = (function() {
  /* Constantes
   *
   */
  var ENDPOINT = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/8056d793049f14ea/'; 

  var exports = {};

  /* Función que obtiene, a partir de la latitud y longitud, el nombre de la ciudad y el código del país
   *
   * @param latitude latitud 
   * @idCountry longitude longitud
   */
  exports.getCityAndCountry = function (latitude, longitude){       
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: ENDPOINT + 'geolookup/q/'+ latitude +','+ longitude +'.json',
      success: function(coords){            
            self.getWeatherData(coords.location.city, coords.location.country_iso3166);             
      }
    });  
  };


  return exports;
})();
```

Puedes utilizar el método de la siguiente manera: `WeatherApi.getCityAndCountry(tuLatitud, tuLongitud)`

Saludos

Comment: Hola vicenrele, sería importante que trasladases a la respuesta la parte que le puede servir a Freddy del ejemplo.

Comment: Hola @MiquelColl, una cosa es hacerle el trabajo a alguien y otra indicarle como puede hacerlo. Y creo que esta última manera es la más provechosa para el interesado. En otro caso podría estar de acuerdo contigo pero en este no lo estoy. Sin embargo he copiado y pegado el código de la fuente que he indicado. Un saludo

Comment: @MiquelColl, Si has quitado un punto al post tú, por ese motivo, quizá puedas reconsiderarlo. Saludos de nuevo

Comment: Una respuesta que es únicamente un link no es una buena respuesta. Puedes aportar links pero es necesario transmitir mas informacion que un link. No se trata de hacer el trabajo pero si dar indicaciones.

Comment: Efectivamente le había puesta un -1 por ser un simple link, retiro mi voto negativo porque ya has aportado información.

Comment: Indico cual es él método que puede utilizar, y está claramente explicado en el comentario del código. No voy a entrar en más discusiones ya que veo que no entiendes lo que quiero decir.

Comment: Gracias por reconsiderarlo. Supongo que será diferencia de opiniones simplemente. Sin más